# Binding a Decimal to NumericUpDown with Minimum other than 0

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I'm binding a decimal (from an NHibernate entity) to a NumericUpDown.

```
_numUpDown.DataBindings.Add(
    New Binding(
        "Value", 
        _BindingSource, 
        "TheDecimal", 
        False, 
        DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
    )
)
```

This works fine. However when I change the minimum value on the NumericUpDown from 0 to .01 I get an error.

From the designer;

```
Me._numUpDown.Minimum = New Decimal(New Integer() {1, 0, 0, 131072})
```

The error;

```
1) System.InvalidOperationException 
---------------------------------------
Message: DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings.
Target: Void FindGoodRow()
Source: System.Windows.Forms
```

What can I do to get it to bind when the minimum value isn't 0?

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10908342/429091, try changing the `formattingEnabled` parameter (that fourth parameter you have set to `False`) to be `True`. This seems to cause .net winforms to ignore the incompatibility between the default decimal value of `0m` and your `NumericUpDown.Minimum`.

With this change, it should appear that the `NumericUpDown` is ignoring any incompatible data and just leaving its `Value` property unmodified in all the cases where you used to get this `InvalidOperationException`. I do not know why this is the case. Maybe the documentation of [`Binding.FormattingEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.formattingenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains it in this excerpt:

> Setting this property to true also enables error-handling behavior and causes the [BindingComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.bindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) event to be raised. The handler of this event can take the appropriate action, based on the success, error, or exceptions in the binding process, by examining the [BindingCompleteState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcompleteeventargs.bindingcompletestate(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [BindingCompleteEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcompleteeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter.

That might mean that if you *wanted* to make the binding fail in this case when formatting is enabled, you’d have to implement that event. I’m not sure how useful this would be. Maybe you would want to notify the user that the value displayed in the `NumericUpDown` does not reflect any data-bound item at the moment (either because the selected item in the list has a value below the `Minimum` or because there is no item currently in the list because it hasn’t been populated yet or there just aren’t any items).